# $this->request->is('post') returns FALSE on form submit

Tags: php, cakephp, request

The MODEL

```
class CompanyCategory extends AppModel
{
    public $name = "CompanyCategory";

    public $hasMany = array(
        "Company"
    );
}
```

The CONTROLLER

```
public function admin_edit($id = null){

            //debug($this->request);
            //exit(0);
            if($id == null){
                $this->Session->setFlash("ID categorie eronat!", "flash/simpla_error");
                $this->redirect("index");
            }
            if($this->request->is('post')){
                if($this->CompanyCategory->save($this->request->data)){
                    $this->Session->setFlash("Categoria a fost salvata!", "flash/simpla_success");
                }
                else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash("Categoria NU a fost salvata!", "flash/simpla_error");
                }
            }
            else{
                $this->Session->setFlash("READ!", "flash/simpla_error");
                $this->request->data = $this->CompanyCategory->read(null, $id);
            }
        }
```

The VIEW

```
<div class="content-box">
    <div class="content-box-header">
        <h3>Editeaza categorie firme</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box-content">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->create("CompanyCategory", array(
                'inputDefaults' => array(
                    'error' => array(
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'wrap' => 'span', 
                            'class' => 'input-notification error png_bg'
                        )                   
                    )
                )
            ));
        ?>

        <?=$this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'))?>

        <?=$this->Form->input('title', array('class' => "text-input small-input", 'label' => 'Denumire'))?>

        <?=$this->Form->submit('Salveaza', array('class' => "button"))?>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when submiting the form, the controller returns false for request->is('false');

If I set explicitly in the view to the form helper inside the create method the type as 'post' it works as expected.

It is a little bit frustrating while the form method is already post without setting it.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Try displaying the value of  `$this->request` using `print_r`. I had a similar problem and for some weird reason the submission method used was PUT instead of POST (your view seems to be fine though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this controller

```
public function admin_edit($id = null) {
        $this->layout = 'admin_layout';
        $this->CompanyCategory->id = $id;
        if (!$this->CompanyCategory->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid CompanyCategory model'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->CompanyCategory->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The CompanyCategory model has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The CompanyCategory model could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->CompanyCategory->read(null, $id);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, Abid, I just saw the fact that Cake is using a hidden field generated by Form helper in order to set/identify the method. While in the add form, where the request->data is null, the hidden field's  with name "_method" value is "POST", in the edit form, where request->data is an array created by read() method of the model, the value is "PUT". Thank's for the answer!

Comment: I think that it can also be used the following in the conditional: (!empty($this->request->data)). It is shorter.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what framework you are using for this but my guess would be in the view in the
$this->Form->create()

There should be an option for you to set the form action type to post.

If you view the html where there PHP code is generating the form is it creating the action property of the  ?  My guess is its probably doing GET by default.