# suddenly $this->request->data stopped working in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am beginner in cakephp and working on a mid level project, where i have many webservices in MyController.ctp file. Now the issue is before 4-5 days suddenly webservices stopped working. and application paused in live mode.

After debugging i found that my POST type api's stopped getting parameters by using `$this->request->data[User][email]`, when i tested, i found a strange thing that api's returning true on `$this->request->is('get')` and false on `$this->request->is('post')`

I don't know the solution and the reason behind this. Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: refferance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832430/this-request-ispost-returns-false-on-form-submit

Comment: check your form if the method send is really a `post`

Comment: @NewbeeDev in webservice i set type post during api calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for `PUT` as well.

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))
```

PUT is the POST HTTP Request version of "edit" action. When your request is made to change data, instead of adding new records, you send a PUT request.

Reference: [CakePHP Doc: Inspecting the request](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#inspecting-the-request)

Comment: Yes you are right, but the issue is- when i am using "$this->request->data['Model']['title']" , this is not fetching data in method, thats why i am unable to go futther.

Comment: Solved : i used "$this->data['ModelName']['FieldName']" to get data from put request. Now every thing is working fine. Thanks

Comment: Only a single query that why it was happened in running code, means this same code was working fine since 1 year and now suddenly it failed, can you please describe the reason behind this.